# Why don't we force carbonate at a higher PSI

Tags: carbonation

A lot of the force carbonation guides that I have seen say to set the psi to 20 and leave it for 4-7 days.

Why don't we just set it to 40 (or higher) and wait 2-3.5 days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume higher pressures aren't used because of the greater possibility for overcarbonation.  If you carbonate a little too long at 20 PSI your beer will be less overcarbonated than if you overcarbonated at 40 PSI.  The room for error/deviation is greater at a lower PSI.  Perhaps there is a more scientific answer...

Comment: yep, there's a greater chance you'll overshoot with a higher pressure

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, I usually set mine at 40psi for 24 hours, then 20psi for 24 hours, then 10psi for 24 hours, and fine tune from there. I usually serve at about 8psi.

Naturally, I pour myself a pint at each interval for quality control purposes. ;)

Comment: I do the same. And "quality control" is one of the perks of being a homebrewer! :)